# PySpark - Group by ID & Date, and Sum in mins by a time column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I am processing my data in Spark, and the problem is similar and can be fixed by like what I did in SQL:
SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', targetcolumn)

But, I am wondering is there anyway to do so by PySpark especially there is only a time column?

My dataframe is like:

```
df= df_temp.show()


|record_date| Tag| time|
+-----------+----+-----+
| 2012-05-05| A |13:14:07.000000|
| 2012-05-05| A |13:54:08.000000|
...................
| 2013-01-01| B |14:40:26.000000|
| 2013-01-01| B |14:48:27.000000|
..................
| 2014-04-03| C |17:17:30.000000|
| 2014-04-03| C |17:47:31.000000|
```

Is it possible, I can do like group by record_date, Tag
then sum up time in mins?
So it will turn out like:

```
  |record_date| Tag| time|
    +-----------+----+-----+
    | 2012-05-05| A |00:41:01.000000|
    | 2013-01-01| B |00:08:01.000000|
    | 2014-04-03| C |00:30:01.000000|
```

Time column could be any format like: 40 in mins or 0.4 hrs.

Thank you

Comment: there is no time format in spark. only timestamp. if you want to process time, you have to choose a unit and process it in this unit as an int or a float. e.g., you put everything in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only two latest rows have to be compared, then Window "lead" function can be used, on Scala:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2012-05-05", "A", "13:14:07.000000"),
  ("2012-05-05", "A", "13:54:08.000000"),
  ("2013-01-01", "B", "14:40:26.000000"),
  ("2013-01-01", "B", "14:48:27.000000"),
  ("2014-04-03", "C", "17:17:30.000000"),
  ("2014-04-03", "C", "17:47:31.000000")
).toDF("record_date", "Tag", "time")

val recordTagWindow = Window.partitionBy("record_date", "Tag").orderBy(desc("time"))

df
  .withColumn("time", substring($"time", 1, 8))
  .withColumn("unixTimestamp", unix_timestamp($"time", "HH:mm:ss"))
  .withColumn("timeDiffSeconds", $"unixTimestamp" - lead($"unixTimestamp", 1, 0).over(recordTagWindow))
  .withColumn("timeDiffFormatted", date_format($"timeDiffSeconds".cast(TimestampType).cast(TimestampType), "HH:mm:ss"))
  .withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(recordTagWindow))
  .where($"rownum" === 1)
  .drop("rownum", "timeDiffSeconds", "time", "unixTimestamp")
```

Output (look like yours example incorrect for first row):

```
+-----------+---+-----------------+
|record_date|Tag|timeDiffFormatted|
+-----------+---+-----------------+
|2012-05-05 |A  |00:40:01         |
|2013-01-01 |B  |00:08:01         |
|2014-04-03 |C  |00:30:01         |
+-----------+---+-----------------+
```

For more than two rows, functions "first" and "last" can be used, and Window modified to include all values (rowsBetween):

```
val recordTagWindow = Window.partitionBy("record_date", "Tag").orderBy(desc("time"))
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df
  .withColumn("time", substring($"time", 1, 8))
  .withColumn("unixTimestamp", unix_timestamp($"time", "HH:mm:ss"))
  .withColumn("timeDiffSeconds", first($"unixTimestamp").over(recordTagWindow) - last($"unixTimestamp").over(recordTagWindow))
  .withColumn("timeDiffFormatted", date_format($"timeDiffSeconds".cast(TimestampType).cast(TimestampType), "HH:mm:ss"))
  .withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("record_date", "Tag").orderBy(desc("time"))))
  .where($"rownum" === 1)
  .drop("rownum", "timeDiffSeconds", "time", "unixTimestamp")
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!
Following up the question,  What if I need to calculate more than two rows?
I have check to use  "lead("column", 2 )". I am wondering can I check the length of the row in a group, then sum up the number  in like  lead("column", len(group) )?

Comment: Solution for more that two rows added on the end of answer.